# ReactJS with ES6: this.props is not a function when I communicate two components

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working with ReactJS with ES6, but I have some problems to communicate child > parent through props. Example of my approach:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  handler(e){
    this.props.filterUser(e.target.value);
  }

  render () {
  return <div>
    <input type='text' className='from-control search-bar' placeholder='Search' onChange={this.handler} />
  </div>
  }
}


export default class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: '', age: '', filter: ''};
  } 

  filterUser(filterValue){
    this.setState({
      filter: filterValue
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <SearchBar filterUser={this.filterUser} />
      <span>Value: {this.state.filter}</span>
    </div>
  }
}
```

This returns `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.filterUser is not a function`.

Any idea? Binding maybe?

**[EDIT] Solution (Thanks @knowbody & @Felipe Skinner):**

I was missing binding in my constructor. Binding in the SearchBar constructor works perfectly.

Using `React.createClass()` (ES5), it automatically does bindings to `this` for your functions. In ES6 you need bind `this` manually. More info https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are missing binding in your constructor, also you don't need to pass `props` if you are not using them in the constructor. Also you need to `import { PropTypes } from 'react'`

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
  }

  handler(e){
    this.props.filterUser(e.target.value);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' className='from-control search-bar' placeholder='Search' onChange={this.handler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default class User extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.filterUser = this.filterUser.bind(this);
    this.state = { name: '', age: '', filter: '' };
  } 

  filterUser(filterValue){
    this.setState({
      filter: filterValue
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <SearchBar filterUser={this.filterUser} />
        <span>Value: {this.state.filter}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! works, but throws an error "unexpected token" setting the propTypes like that. `SearchBar.propTypes = {
  filterUser: React.PropTypes.func
};` works better.

Comment: sorry fixed it, what I have used before is the ES7 way https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es7-property-initializers

Comment: Yes, of course. Anyway this works without setting propTypes, you are right: I was missing binding in my constructor. Binding in the SearchBar constructor works perfectly.

Comment: Hey , I am trying the similar implementation in reactnative , but it throws error "this.props.filterUser is not a function". Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong. My code is smilar to what is there in the solution above

Comment: @AbhinandanSahgal can you show me your code? maybe paste it into a gist so I can comment there?

Answer (score 6):

When ur using React.createClass(), it automatically does bindings to this for your functions.

Since you're using the ES6 class syntax, you need to do those bindings by yourself. Here's two options:

```
render() {
    return <div>
      <SearchBar filterUser={this.filterUser.bind(this)} />
      <span>Value: {this.state.filter}</span>
    </div>
  }
```

Or you could bind it on your constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: '', age: '', filter: ''};
    this.filterUser = this.filterUser.bind(this);
  }
```

You can read about this on the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

**Note that those two options are mutually exclusive.**

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was importing the component the wrong way. I have the components "HomeAdmin" and "Register".

I had this in HomeAdmin.js:
`import { Register } from "/path/to/register"`

Changed to this and worked:
`import Register from "/path/to/register"`

Answer (score 0):

it can be also a mis export:

wrong:
export function name ...

export default name

correct:

function name
export default name