# Unable to call a property of child react component from parent react component

Tags: reactjs

Following is the `jsx` code of `child & parent` parent react components. **I am trying to pass the data from child react component to parent react component as property (`generateReport`)** but it throws the error as

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.generateReport is not a function
>       at MetricsReport.generateReport (metrics-report.jsx:40)

**child.jsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Input,
  Collapsible,
  CollapsibleItem
} from 'react-materialize';

class MetricsReport extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      metricsParams: { reportType: '' }
    };
    this.getReportType = this.getReportType.bind(this);
    // Add the below line as per the answer but still facing the problem
    this.generateReport = this.generateReport.bind(this);
  }
  getReportType(event) {
    console.log(this.state.metricsParams);
    let metricsParams = { ...this.state.metricsParams };
    metricsParams.reportType = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ metricsParams });
  }

  generateReport() {
    this.props.generateReport(this.state.metricsParams);
  }
  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="ushubLeftPanel">
        <label>{'Report Type'}</label>
        <select
          id="metricsDropDown"
          className="browser-default"
          onChange={this.getReportType}
        >
          <option value="MetricsByContent">Metrics By Content</option>
          <option value="MetricsByUser">Metrics By User</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick={this.generateReport}>Generate Report</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MetricsReport;
```

**parent.jsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MetricsReport from '../components/pages/metrics-report';

class MetricsReportContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.generateReport = this.generateReport.bind(this);
  }
  generateReport(metricsParams) {
    console.log(metricsParams);
  }
  componentDidMount() {}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MetricsReport generateReport={this.generateReport} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default metricsReportContainer;
```

Comment: bind `generateReport` function as you have done for `getReportType`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS with ES6: this.props is not a function when I communicate two components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141444/reactjs-with-es6-this-props-is-not-a-function-when-i-communicate-two-components)

Comment: I have done as per suggestion:
 `this.generateReport = this.generateReport.bind(this);`
But still throwing the same error

Comment: I have done similar implementation and its working fine. Please have a look. https://codesandbox.io/s/kk89834r3o

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind the context `this` inside child component `MetricsReport`:

```
// inside the constructor
this.generateReport = this.generateReport.bind(this);
```

But you may simply use like this:

```
<button 
  onClick={this.props.generateReport(this.state.metricsParams)}
>
  Generate Report
</button>
```

Comment: Still facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can handle these scenarios by using anonymous functions instead of normal function. Anonymous function handles your this and removes the need to binding.

`generateReport(metricsParams) {
    console.log(metricsParams);
  }`

becomes

`generateReport = (metricsParams) => {
    console.log(metricsParams);
  }`

Also in child class

`generateReport() {
    this.props.generateReport(this.state.metricsParams);
  }`

becomes

`generateReport = () => {
    var metricsParams = this.state.metricsParams;
    this.props.generateReport(metricsParams);
  }`