# TypeError: this.props.searchYelp is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, typeerror

Just so you know I am a beginner at javascript and react.js. 
I am working on a project from Codecademy and I am stuck on an error code.

Error code I'm receiving:

```
    TypeError: this.props.searchYelp is not a function. (In 'this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy)', 'this.props.searchYelp' is undefined)

    handleSearch
    src/components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js:26
      23 | }
      24 | 
      25 | handleSearch(event) {
    > 26 |     this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy);
   ^  27 |     event.preventDefault();
      28 | }
      29 | 

enter code hereView compiled
```

---

My SearchBar.js code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './SearchBar.css';

    const sortByOptions = {
        'Best Match' : 'best_match',
        'Highest Rated' : 'rating',
        'Most Rated' : 'review_count'
    };

    class SearchBar extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                terms:'',
                location:'',
                sortBy:'best_match'
            };

            this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
            this.handleLocationChange = this.handleLocationChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
        }

        handleSearch(event) {
            this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy);
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        handleTermChange(event) {
            this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
        }

            handleLocationChange(event) {
            this.setState({ location: event.target.value });
        }

        getSortByClass(sortByOption) {
            if (sortByOption === this.state.sortBy) {
                return 'active';
            }
            return '';
        }

        handleSortByChange(sortByOption) {
            this.setState({ sortBy: sortByOption });
        }




        renderSortByOptions() {
            return Object.keys(sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
                let sortByOptionValue = sortByOptions[sortByOption];
                return <li key={sortByOptionValue} onClick={this.handleSortByChange.bind(this, sortByOptionValue)} className={this.getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)} >{sortByOption}</li>
            });
        }


        render() {
            return (
                <div className="SearchBar">
                    <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
                        <ul>
                            {this.renderSortByOptions()}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className="SearchBar-fields">
                        <input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange={this.handleTermChange} />
                        <input placeholder="Where?" onChange={this.handleLocationChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="SearchBar-submit">
                        <a onClick={this.handleSearch} href="www.#.com">Let's Go</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default SearchBar;
```

---

My App.js code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar/SearchBar';
    import BusinessList from './components/BusinessList/BusinessList';

    const business = {
      imageSrc: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/programs/react/ravenous/pizza.jpg',
      name: 'MarginOtto Pizzeria',
      address: '1010 Paddington Way',
      city: 'Flavortown',
      state: 'NY',
      zipCode: '10101',
      category: 'Italian',
      rating: 4.5,
      reviewCount: 90
    };

    const businesses = [business, business, business, business, business, business];

    class App extends Component {

      seachYelp(term, location, sortBy) {
        console.log(`Searching Yelp with ${term}, ${location}, and ${sortBy}`);
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>ravenous</h1>
            <SearchBar searchYelp={this.searchYelp} />
            <BusinessList businesses={businesses} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

---

Is anybody able to help me? Where have I gone wrong?

I have google my error code and can’t seem to find a solution…

Also, please let me know if you require any more information...

Thanks!

Katie

Comment: is searchYelp a function ? if so where is it?

Comment: The error is right. There is no ``searchYelp`` function in your ``SearchBar`` class

Comment: Where do you render `SearchBar`? Please show us

Comment: kindly share JSX code too something like `<SearchBar searchYelp={()=>{//UR CODE} } />` share your `app.js` or `User.js` file please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141444/reactjs-with-es6-this-props-is-not-a-function-when-i-communicate-two-components

Comment: Can you share your App.js file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't worry I made a typo error in the App.js, it's working now!

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are rendering your searchbar and passing your function state,
binding this as using this context in another child component,
Yelp is another const var declared.

Your app.js should be like,

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
 businesses:[]
};
this.searchYelp = this.searchYelp.bind(this);
}

searchYelp(term, location, sortBy){


       Yelp.search(term,location,sortBy)
       .then(businesses=>{this.setState
       ({
               businesses:businesses});
       });

   } 

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.businesses);    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>ravenous</h1>
        <SearchBar searchYelp = {this.searchYelp}/>
        <BusinessList businesses={this.state.businesses}/>   
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

searchbar.js be like,

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      term: '',
      location: '',
      sortBy: 'best_match'
    };

    this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLocationChange = this.handleLocationChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);

    this.sortByOptions = {
      'Best Match': 'best_match',
      'Highest Rated': 'rating',
      'Most Reviewed': 'review_count'
    };
  }

  getSortByClass(sortByOption) {
    if (this.state.sortBy === sortByOption) {
      return 'active';
    }
    return '';
  }

  handleSortByChange(sortByOption) {
    this.setState({sortBy: sortByOption});
  }

  handleTermChange(event) {
    this.setState({term: event.target.value});
  }

  handleLocationChange(event) {
    this.setState({location: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSearch(event) {
    this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy);

    event.preventDefault();
  }

  renderSortByOptions() {
    return Object.keys(this.sortByOptions).map(sortByOption => {
      let sortByOptionValue = this.sortByOptions[sortByOption];
      return (<li className={this.getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)}
                  key={sortByOptionValue}
                  onClick={this.handleSortByChange.bind(this, sortByOptionValue)}>
                {sortByOption}
             </li>);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchBar">
        <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
          <ul>
            {this.renderSortByOptions()}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="SearchBar-fields">
          <input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange={this.handleTermChange} />
          <input placeholder="Where?" onChange={this.handleLocationChange}/>
        </div>
        <div className="SearchBar-submit">
          <a onClick={this.handleSearch}>Let's Go</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SearchBar;
```

yelp.js be like,

```
const clientId = 'KnUCjsgC_SwsKbyWhoY_KQ';
const secret = 'H26mxyT3NsVNCTCLf21NjPtPI0PRWKZUIWbkyycSf1Pzv7xPOjh7wCz1YyiSEoaO';
let accessToken;

//object
const Yelp ={
    getAccessToken(){
        if(accessToken){
            return new Promise(resolve =>resolve(accessToken));
        } 
        return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials& client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${secret}`,
        {method:'POST'
        }).then(response =>{
        return response.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {accessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;
      }); 
    },


    search(term, location, sortBy) {
    return Yelp.getAccessToken().then(() => {
      return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=${term}&location=${location}&sort_by=${sortBy}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
      });
    }).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(jsonResponse => {
      if (jsonResponse.businesses) {
        console.log(jsonResponse.businesses);
        return jsonResponse.businesses.map(business => ({
          id: business.id,
          imageSrc: business.image_url,
          name: business.name,
          address: business.location.address1,
          city: business.location.city,
          state: business.location.state,
          zipCode: business.location.zip_code,
          category: business.categories[0].title,
          rating: business.rating,
          reviewCount: business.review_count
        }));
      }
    });
  }
};
export default Yelp;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the declaration of your function (searchYelp) and why did you pass it as props? , you have just to declare it and then call it.

```
searchYelp=()=>{//what your function do}


 handleSearch(event) {
 this.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy);
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of your function is false, try this:

```
 searchYelp=(term, location, sortBy)=>{


           Yelp.search(term,location,sortBy)
           .then(businesses=>{this.setState
           ({
                   businesses:businesses});
           });

       }
```