# props.dogs.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, filter

I have a search bar and a card that displays a dog name. I want to use the search bar to filter the dog's name. Right now I am getting the error props.dogs.map is not a function.

In the DogCard component, I have changed props.dogs to props.filteredName but I am still getting the error. I also looked at  [ReactJS with ES6: this.props is not a function when I communicate two components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141444/reactjs-with-es6-this-props-is-not-a-function-when-i-communicate-two-components), because it was similar to my error. I have tried handleFilterName={this.handleFilterName.bind(this)} and handleFilterName={e => this.handleFilterName(e)} but I am still getting the same error.

```
class SelectDogs extends Component {
 state = {
     dogs: 
        [ {
             name: 'Jack',
             breed: 'beagle',
             age:'2',
         }
     ],
     filteredName: ''
 }



 handleFilterName = (e) => {

     const dogs = this.state.dogs
     const filteredDogName = dogs.filter( dog => {
     return (
         dog.name.search(e.currentTarget.value) !== -1
       );

     })
     this.setState({filteredName: filteredDogName})  
 }


 render() {
     return (
         <div>
             <NavHeader/>
             <SearchDog handleFilterName={this.handleFilterName}/>
             <DogCard  dogs={this.state.filteredName}></DogCard>
         </div>
     )
 }
}
export default SelectDogs 



const SearchDog = (props) => {

 return (

   <div className="search-container">
      <Form  inline onChange={props.handleFilterName}>
         <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search a Dog" className=" mr-sm-2" />
         <Button type="submit"><FaSistrix/></Button>
      </Form>
   </div>


 )


}

export default SearchDog

const DogCard = (props) => {


return props.dogs.map( dog => 
     {
         return <div className="dog-container"><Card className="dog-card" key={dog.name}><Link to='/dog'>{dog.name}</Link></Card></div>

     })



}

export default DogCard
```

Comment: First of all, replace "strain" with "dog" in your .map method.
Second of all, console.log props in DogCard: console.log(props.dogs) and look what will you get.

Comment: what result you get when you console this.state.filteredName the error is around this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, in your initial state definition `filteredName` is a String, and you call an Array method map on it.

Change the beginning to

```
class SelectDogs extends Component {
 state = {
     dogs: 
        [ {
             name: 'Jack',
             breed: 'beagle',
             age:'2',
         }
     ],
     filteredName: []
 }
...
```

and everything should be ok.

I assume the problem is in bad property name, if you rename it to `filteredDogs` the problem would be visible on the first sight.